# Laravel Storage put method returns true

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

In my `laravel`-application I have a `<form>` where it is possible to upload multiple files. When I submit the form the multiple files get stored into the `database`, but the table column `attachment`, which is supposed to store the path of the file, always displays `1` (true).

```
if (request()->has('attachment_files')) {
    $files = request()->attachment_files;

    foreach ($files as $file) {

      $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $filesize = $file->getClientSize();

      $path = Storage::disk('local')->put('attachments' . $filename, $extension);
      $data = SingleApplicationFile::create([
         'files_id' => $application->id,
         'single_application_id' => $application->id,
         'attachment' => $path,
         'attachment_name' => $filename,
         'attachment_size' => $filesize,
      ]);

      $attachment_file[] = $data;

      new SingleApplicationFile($attachment_file);
   }
}
```

As mentioned, the line `$path = Storage::disk('local')->put('attachments' . $filename, $extension);` always gives me `true` and in the database column a "1" is stored.

I used this method before for single file upload, and in that case, the mentioned line stores `attachments/somefilename.pdf` - so what is the issue here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`put()` returns a boolean value](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L192), which is why you are seeing a `1` in your database column and not the string path to your stored file.  You might be thinking of `putFile()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Next you need to run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and then you can retrieve the file as

```
{{ asset('storage/attachments' . $filename) }}
```

so you may like to save as

```
if ( Storage::disk('local')->put('attachments' . $filename, $extension) ) {
    $path = 'storage/attachments' . $filename;
}
```